# apache2 -> psp -> logging -> какая-то дубляжка в лог. Ничего не понимаю!

Tags: python, linux, apache2, логирование, apache-modules

Linux aka Debian, apache2 задаёт mod_python запрос через psp, psp пишет свой лог:

```
import logging
```

Обычный модуль, ничего не делаю. Если скрипт с консоли запускаю - всё как надо.

Если psp отрабатывает от apache, то первый запрос пишет нормально, второй дублирует в лог, каждая запись дважды, третий - трижды, четвёртый - четырежды и так до 10, минимум. Т.е. один и тот же `logger.info` пишется в ряд по 10 раз.

Как-будто это каждый поток apache выполняет себя, но на самом деле - выполняется всего лишь раз, в скрипте есть locker, который не замыкает.

Делаю:

```
logger.info("My pid: " + str( os.getpid() ) )
```

Открываю в браузере несколько раз подряд http://127.0.0.1/myscript.psp

В лог падает:

```
- INFO - My pid: 11931
- INFO - My pid: 11931
- INFO - My pid: 8036
- INFO - My pid: 8036
- INFO - My pid: 8036
- INFO - My pid: 29092
- INFO - My pid: 29092
- INFO - My pid: 29092
- INFO - My pid: 29092
...
```

Пид 1 и тот же, значит скрипт отрабатывает 1 раз, правильно?

Почему тогда так лог флудится?

**Edit:**

пид этот - апача.

В скрипте делаю создания файла с случайной меткой random.random() и пишу туда метку времени time.time() - каждый раз по 1-му файлу и по 1-ой метке времени в каждом. Т.е. скрипт-то отрабатывает 1 раз, но вот лог шумит, что-то отлаживать просто невозможно.

Comment: Посмотри что у тебя под этим pid. небось сам апач. Если я правильно понимаю mod_python подгружает скрипты на выполнение в сам процесс апача. так что pid не показатель. И загляни в логи самого апача, сколько вызовов реально делал браузер.

Comment: да, это апач. как его починить? В логе access апача всего 1 GET.

Comment: Ну я просто сказал, как скрипт запущен и что pid не показатель. а так я с питоном не сталкивался и не знаю, что за логгер и как он может работать. надо знатоков подождать